# Laravel return relationship with raw query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I am trying to write a query where I can return an array of posts that have related users to it. Basically, I want to return something like what `with()` does using Eloquent but instead, I want to achieve it with `raw()` query. Currently, I am doing something like the following:

```
DB::select('SELECT * FROM posts LEFT JOIN users ON posts.user_id = users.id');
```

I am getting the results in one object with 0 depth and I want the user to be in a separate object inside so I can access it like `post.user.name`. I want my response to be like the following

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Praesentium molestiae",
        "status": 1,
        "type": 1,
        "author": {
             "name": "John Doe",
             "email": "johndoe@email.com"
        }
    },
...
```

**User Model**

```
public function posts() 
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post','user_id');
}
```

**Posts Model**

```
public function user() 
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

Comment: Can you post what you already have? Does it fail somewhere, do you get any errors? What is your question?

Comment: @brombeer currently i am doing something like this
DB::select('SELECT * FROM posts LEFT JOIN users ON posts.user_id = users.id');

And i am getting the results in one object with 0 depth ... I want user to be in separate object inside ... so i can access like post.user.name

Answer (score 0):

make a post resource to handle this issue

**PostController**

```
<?php

  namespace App\Http\Controllers;

  use App\Http\Resources\PostResource;
  use App\Models\Post;
  use Illuminate\Http\Request;

  class PostController extends Controller
  {
    public function index()
    {
     return PostResource::collection(Post::latest()->get());
    }
  }
```

**PostResource**

```
<?php

  namespace App\Http\Resources;

  use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

  class PostResource extends JsonResource
  {
   /**
   * Transform the resource into an array.
   *
   * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
   * @return array
   */
   public function toArray($request)
   {
     return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'name' => $this->name,
        'status' => $this->status,
        'type' => $this->type,
        'author' => $this->user,
    ];
   }
}
```

Comment: This returns the result in one object ... i want user to be a separate object inside each post ... so i can access post.user.name

Comment: The approach is ok ... it works ... but its not very efficient performance wise ... This approach creates local models after each database fetch and for 2000 entries in the database it takes 7 seconds to get them all ... Raw query takes 200ms to get them all